# Php echo XML only part of the content

Tags: php, xml, parsing

Begginer question,

Im trying to make a webapp and I only need the hour from this XML instead of the full date, using PHP echo.

```
<StartTime>2013-08-03 22:59:00</StartTime>
```

Is it possible? If yes, how? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should post what you've tried so far. There's a couple of libraries that might help. SimpleXML (http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or DOMDocument (http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). If you post what you've tried someone might be able to give you an example of a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your code but you could use something like this:

```
// load xml file with simplexml
$data = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
echo substr($data->StartTime, -8, 2);
```

Comment: At this moment it's just a simple code that im starting just to understand how it works and in this case, this solution worked perfectly. Thanks Perry. And Thanks everybody that helped too with other great solutions.

Answer (score 2):

$hour = date("H");
/*
h   12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    01 through 12
H   24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    00 through 23
*/
additional information see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can grab the date out of the XML. You can do something like:

```
$dateString = "2013-08-03 22:59:00";
$hour = date("h", strtotime($dateString));
echo $hour;
```

See it in action here: http://codepad.org/QraqKa3c

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression':

```
$arr = array();
preg_match('/\<[^\>]+\>[^\ ]+\ ([0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2})\<\/[^\>]+\>/i', "<StartTime>2013-08-03 22:59:00</StartTime>", $arr);
echo $arr[1];
```